# Get all id from a page and their style attribute

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a CSS-file and have this code below. But here it "alerts" the style attribute for each element (quite logical based on the code) But how can I get all of the elements attribute with a loop like `PrintCss = "#" + id + "{" + cssMap[id]+"}";`

So later I can use it to save it as a CSS-file?

```
    var cssMap = {};
    $('[id^="textHolder"],[id^="youtubeHolder"],[id^="imgHolder"],[id^="mapHolder"],[id^="fb-iframe"],[id^="fb-beforelike"],[id^="quiz-container"], [id^="bfTextHolder"]').each(function(){
    cssMap[this.id] = $(this).attr('style');
    });
    for(id in cssMap) {      
        PrintCss = "#" + id + "{" + cssMap[id]+"}";

          alert(PrintCss)

      }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Append to a string instead of `alert()`ing? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To build an array of the ids of the page, you can do

```
var ids = $('[id]').map(function(){return this.id}).get()
```

To directly build a map id -> style, do

```
var cssMap = {};
$('[id]').each(function(){ cssMap[this.id]=this.style });
```

Or to directly build your css :

```
PrintCss = '';
$('[id]').each(function(){ PrintCss += this.id + '{' + this.style + '}\n' });
```